# How to create columns dynamically in a asp:gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to make a column in Gridview whose values acts as a hyperlink.
The hyperlink url is made up of parts supplied from dataset

```
Foreach(dRow in Tables[0].Row)
{
url = "<a href=ClientView.aspx?\"" + dRow["client_id"].ToString() +"</a>";
}
```

How can I generate column in gridview which shows this link ?

Other columns are defined in markup.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Sno" HeaderText="SNo" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Name" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to add column ClientId between gridview's **SNo** and **ClientName** column whose text is obtained from dataset row `drow["clientid"]` field and is enclosed between anchor tags to behave like url.

Comment: Is your `GridView` declared in your markup, or created in your code-behind files?

Comment: its in markup with `autogenerate=false`

Comment: Can you show your `GridView` markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well to add to your existing code, add a templatefield.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Sno" HeaderText="SNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientName" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="gvlbtnClientVIew"
              PostBackUrl='<%# "ClientView.aspx?client_id=" + Eval("client_id") %>'
              Text='<%# Bind("client_id") %>'>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a `TemplateField` in your header, you don't need to create it dynamically:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:hyperlink runat="server" id="hlClientView"
                  NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ClientView.aspx?client_id={0}", Eval("client_id")) %>'
                  Text='<%# Eval("client_id") %>'>
                </asp:hyperlink>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```